# How to change the docker of the docker extension of vscode on ubuntu?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I have two dockers on my `Ubuntu 22.04`.

One is from `snap` and one is from `apt` installation.

When  I disable the `snap-docker` service, the containers are not showing up in vscode. But these containers are all built with the `apt-docker`.

So I suppose the extension is using the `snap-docker` for it's service. Is there a way to change it to the `apt-docker` so that I can delete the `snap-docker` to keep the system clean.

In short, the vscode extension is using `snap.docker.dockerd.service` instead of `docker.service`. How can I change it to the latter?

Vscode docker extension ID: `ms-azuretools.vscode-docker`

Comment: Remove the snap version, then remove snap completely from your system and never use it again. Preferably, stop using ubuntu and move to Garuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved by using one installation by the office installation method. uninstall snap and the extension 'Docker'.